# Two solutions to one number.

Tags: exponentiation

I met a question which said :

*Find the value of*

$\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{.^{.^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}}}$

Now to start I declared

$y=\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{.^{.^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}}}$

Now this implies that

$y=\sqrt2^y$

Now solving this equation we get

$y=2,4$

but then how can a single number have two values. So where am I going wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: Just because the question says "Find **the** value", doesn't mean the question was well formulated. Perhaps it should have said "Find **a** value** or "Find **all** values".

Comment: I can't exactly recall what the question said but the main problem is that how can one number give out two values. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: [see this](https://jeremykun.com/2012/05/05/false-proof-2-4-as-the-limit-of-an-infinite-power-tower/).  [see also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800862/convergence-of-power-towers?rq=1).

Comment: note that $\sqrt{2}<2$ and if $0<x<2$ then $\sqrt{2}^x<2$

Comment: You've written down mere symbols. Only if you assume that has a value, you get your equation. So just start with a reasonable definition.

Comment: @Adam That doesn't necessarily prove anything; what if the limit is $2$?

Comment: @Théophile it proves that it certainly cannot be 4

Comment: @Adam I see; I misunderstood your point.

Comment: If you sketch the curves $y=2^x$ and $y=x^2$, then you'll see that they cross in three places. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex%3Dx%5E2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421293/is-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-4-correct is worth a look.

Comment: Here's an analogy.  Suppose I asked "what is the value of $\sqrt{25}$?  It is a single number." and you reasoned.  If $x = \sqrt{25}$ then $x^2 = \sqrt{25}^ 2 = 25$.  But $(-5)^2= 25$ and $5^2=25$.  So $x = 5$ and it equals $-5$.  How can a single number have two values.  The error is assuming that $x = \sqrt{2}^x$ has only one solution.  Your number is *one* of the solutions.  Hint: $\sqrt{2} < 2$ so $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ so by induction $x$ (if it exists) is $\le 2$.

Comment: $x^2 = 4 $ has two solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m sorry, but I have to disagree with all the previous answers except that of @JanEerland. It seems to me that the infinite expression that you have written can be interpreted in only one way, as the limit of a sequence, which we must show to be convergent. If we do this, the limit is unique.

The sequence is defined recursively as follows:
\begin{align}
a_0&=\sqrt2\\
a_{n+1}&=\sqrt2^{a_n}\quad\text{for }n\ge0\\
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n
\end{align}
One sees easily that $a_n<2$ for all $n$, and a little less easily that the sequence is increasing. Your computation gives two possible values, but only one of these is $\le2$, and hence that one is the value, to the extent that the expression is to be viewed as a limit.

Comment: From a logical standpoint, what you (correctly) did was to say, “If this expression means anything, it means either $2$ or $4$.” The remaining step, to find that it *does* mean something, is what I and others have supplied.

Answer (score 1):

The paradox arises when you assume that a solution exists and in fact there is no solution.  To solve the paradox you check your proposed solution against the original equation.

Thus if a positive value of $x$ satisfies $x^{x^{x^...}}=4$ then it must also satisfy $x^4=4$, thus $x=\sqrt{2}$.  If a positive value of $x$ satisfies $x^{x^{x^...}}=2$ then it must also satisfy $x^2=2$, thus $x=\sqrt{2}$.  Clearly not both can be correct and whichevever one fails to check out implies that that case has no solution.  We find that in fact putting in $x=\sqrt{2}$ gives $x^{x^{x^...}}=2$ so we conclude that $x^{x^{x^...}}=4$ has no solution.